# Ответ на собственный вопрос

Tags: обсуждение, самоответы

Сложилась следующая ситуация, задал вопрос [php filesize не может определить размер картинки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/555027/php-filesize-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) в итоге разобрался с проблемой самостоятельно и понятно выложил ответ. Проблема оказалась не в конкретном месте а дальше в программе. Вопрос в следующем. как поступить в данной ситуации, просто удалить вопрос или закрыть или как?

Comment: если нашел ответ сам - опубликуй его как ответ

Comment: @Grundy, опубликовал, но что с самим вопросом делать дальше? проблема то скрывалась не по теме вопроса...

Comment: ну можно внести изменения в исходный вопрос или же удалить этот и задать новый с публикацией ответа на него, а старый стоит удалить

Comment: @Bald Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @Bald, тоесть сформировать вопрос таким образом что б ответ являлся правильным но уже не на изначальный вопрос?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

В описанном Вами случае редактирование исходного вопроса вполне уместно, т.к. в ходе решения возникшего вопроса Вы смогли узнать *истинную* причину и смогли найти ответ на свой вопрос самостоятельно и **отсутствуют** другие ответы, то Вы можете как *переписать* полностью вопрос так и внести *изменения* в исходный вопрос.

Я бы наверно в этом случае не стал переписывать *полностью* исходный вопрос(что бы получить репу за опубликованный ответ), а внес уточнение, например:

> *Исходный текст вопроса*
>
> ---
>
> **Upd:** *Причина обновления*

---

P.S.: Редактирование исходного вопроса не приветствуется в случае если был дан ответ который отвечает на исходный вопрос, и Вы своим обновлением делаете его **не валидным**