# Я хочу задать вопрос, на который знаю ответ

Tags: обсуждение, ассоциация-вопросов, самоответы

Я хочу задать вопрос, на который уже есть ответ на английском языке. При этом, мой вопрос будет агрегировать несколько других вопросов и давать ссылку на статью.

Как мне это лучше сделать?

Comment: Задавайте! Агрегируйте! Из этого получаются хорошие ответы.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Несколько общих слов: самоответы приветствуются:

- [Аккумуляция знаний на SO самоответами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6300/15479).
- [Нужно ли дополнительно поощрять самоответы?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2393/15479).
- [Ответ на собственный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3542/15479).

Если это перевод английского вопроса/ответа, то подпадает под [ассоциация-вопросов](/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2), они тоже приветствуются:

- [Создание связей между одинаковыми вопросами на разных языках](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431/15479).
- [Инструменты ассоциации вопросов между сайтами](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4857/15479).

Идеальный вариант - написать полный ответ с ссылками на оригиналы. Если ответ выходит слишком большой, то в ваш ответ перенести ключевое из оригинальных ответов/статей и оставить ссылки.

Comment: И поставить ассоциацию на один (самый подходящий) ответ.

Comment: @A K, если сделать так, как сказано здесь: «написать полный ответ с ссылками на оригиналы», то найти самый подходящий ответ/ вопрос очень трудно! [См.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9823/185618)