# Давайте улучшим ассоциацию

Tags: предложение, ассоциация-вопросов

У меня есть 2 предложения:
1. Ассоциировать не только вопросы, но и ответы.
2. Ассоциировать один русский вопрос/ответ с несколькими английскими.

Давайте рассмотрим вот такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001185/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F/1001186#1001186), как решить определенную задачу в Убунту.
К нему есть 2 ответа: решение с `systemd` и решение с `crontab`. Ответ про `crontab` ссылается на 2 вопроса: [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times) и [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/567955/automatic-shutdown-at-specified-times).
Вот с чем это все можно ассоциировать?
Если человек искал, как решить эту задачу, то его можно перенаправить в вопрос.
Если человек искал, как работает `crontab`, или почему не работает `crontab`, то его можно направить в ответ про `crontab` из родственных английских вопросов.

При существующей ассоциации непонятно, что тут делать.

Вот похожий [вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9805/185618) на Мете, может он считается за дубль.